# Set Hive priory for individual query/ connection

Tags: python, hive

Our team uses python to execute hive queries. However, a heavy query always blocks other light-weight queries and has to wait more than an hour.

Is it possible to set the priority or vcpu resources for an individual connection?

Is setting the "`yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores`" or "`mapred.job.priority`" in the configuration a solution?

```
configuration = {
    "mapred.job.priority": 'LOW',
    "yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores": 2
}
# configuration={}

con = hive.connect(ip, port=10000, auth=auth, kerberos_service_name='hive', database=db_name, configuration=configuration)
```

If yes, how can I fix the `It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime` error?

Thanks

Comment: Could you pls add - `mem_limit=300000000` ? this will limit each connection.

Comment: @Koushik Roy , It throws `It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are directly connecting to Hive, it seems that the value of `hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist.append` in your settings is incorrect or to strict and does not allow your variables to be set at runtime.

The solution is described here [here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/38501413784/). An example hiveserver2.xml values with values in regex:

```
<property>
    <name>hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist.append</name>
    <value>mapred.*|hive.*|mapreduce.*|spark.*</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist</name>
    <value>mapred.*|hive.*|mapreduce.*|spark.*</value>
</property>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. To the captioned issued, would you prefer setting the `mapred.job.priority`, `yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores` or `mem_limit`?

Comment: I think job priority only has an influence on jobs that are in a queue before they get started. So I would look at the total cpu en memory resources and set the long running job to a certain fraction of that. For example 50%. So the other part of the resources can be used by the smaller jobs.